# Python numpy sort 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I am trying to sort a numpy array using this very simple code:

```
print np.array([2,0,8,4,1]).sort()
```

However, I am getting the result:

```
None
```

Can someone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The array probably gets sorted in-place, like Python's `list.sort()` does so you don't get fooled into thinking the original array is still the same.

```
arr = np.array([2,0,8,4,1])
arr.sort()
print arr
```

Comment: @user1220022: If you just can, please also accept the answer. :)